# trouble drawing a histogram in R - x must be numeric

Tags: r

i am trying to draw a histogram in R but it tells me the error:

> Error in hist.default(group, las = 1, main = "Frequency", xlab = "group (quantity)") :
> 'x' must be numeric

below is my code:

```
CD = read.csv("Bees.csv")
View(CD)
Survey = read.csv("Bees.csv", na.strings = c(""," ","NA"))
attach(Survey)
View(Survey)

hist(group, las=1, main="Frequency", xlab="group (quantity)")

library(FSA)
op = group(oma=c(0,0,1.5,0), mar=c(3,3,2,1))
hist(group ~ mass,
     las=1,
     nrow=2, ncol=1,
     cex.main=0.9, cex.lab=0.8, cex.axis=0.8,
     mgp=c(1.8,0.6,0),
     xlab="group (quantity)" # x-axis title
)
mtext("Frequency", side=3, outer=TRUE, font=2)
par(op)
```

i wrote it all in, but the error actually occurs early on at:

`hist(group, las=1, main="Frequency", xlab="group (quantity)")`

Could someone please help me to see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like one of your variables, which is a number, has been read in as numeric. If you do `str(CD)` are Frequency and group (quantity) both numeric? Sometimes these are read in as character or factor if you don't otherwise specify.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `group` does not seem to be a numeric variable. It might be a character vector, which may not be plotted as a histogram. Use `summary(group)` to check whether there actually are numeric values (the summary should show min, max, median and mean if it is numeric).

If it does not contain numeric values but characters, a histogram is the wrong diagram type. You might want a barplot. Draw it by using the syntax: `barplot(table(group))`